# Java - Collections.sort doesn't work for me on List<MyObject>

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a list with objects which include the lastname of people. I want to sort this list in ascending order but the sort method doesn't work on my list. 
Here is the code:

```
  Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<KeyValue>()
  {
     public int compare(final KeyValue keyValue1, final KeyValue keyValue2)
     {
        return keyValue1.getLastName().compareTo(keyValue2.getLastName());
     }

  });
```

Comment: What does your list contain? Do you know?

Comment: An element of the list looks like this: KeyValue(UserKey: 30689(String); LastName: Bauer; FirstName: Stefan)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get a compiler error, or a runtime error? What is the error message? What result do you expect and how does what it actually does differ from what you expected?

Comment: Try 'new Comparator<Object>()' and casting 'Object' to 'KeyValue' in the 'compare' method.

Comment: You should show us the full code - along with an example and actual output vs. expected output.

Comment: I don't get any error, but the list is still unordered. For example the output ist: Mauer, Bauer, Friedrich. But it should be Bauer, Friedrich, Mauer.

Comment: Does the comparator work if you test it by itself? What is the output of `<your comparator>.compare(<Mauer-object>, <Bauer-object>)`?

Comment: I tried it with the casting and I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide a [MVC example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I have to guess what your objects are, but it works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<KeyValue> resultList = new ArrayList<KeyValue>();
    resultList.add(new KeyValue("Mauer"));
    resultList.add(new KeyValue("Bauer"));
    resultList.add(new KeyValue("Friedrich"));

    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(resultList.toArray(new KeyValue[0])));

    Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<KeyValue>() {
        public int compare(final KeyValue keyValue1, final KeyValue keyValue2) {
            return keyValue1.getLastName().compareTo(keyValue2.getLastName());
        }
    });

    System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.toString(resultList.toArray(new KeyValue[0])));
}

static class KeyValue {
    private String lastName;

    public KeyValue(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Before: [Mauer, Bauer, Friedrich] 
>   After: [Bauer, Friedrich, Mauer]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I solved it now.

The sorting doesn't worked because the last values which are added to the list are lowercased. It works with the compareToIgnoreCase() method.

```
Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<KeyValue>()
{
 public int compare(final KeyValue keyValue1, final KeyValue keyValue2)
 {
    return keyValue1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(keyValue2.getLastName());
 }

});
```